# VirtualizingObservableCollection in UWP Application

Tags: wpf, uwp

I'm trying to use the [VirtualizingObservableCollection](https://github.com/anagram4wander/VirtualizingObservableCollection) in a UWP application. It is a PCL library so I was hoping I could link it in directly and use it. I've never done WPF and am new to UWP and XAML.

Part of the initialization for the collection is the following code:

```
if ( !VirtualizationManager.IsInitialized )
{
    //set the VirtualizationManager’s UIThreadExcecuteAction. In this case
    //we’re using Dispatcher.Invoke to give the VirtualizationManager access
    //to the dispatcher thread, and using a DispatcherTimer to run the background
    //operations the VirtualizationManager needs to run to reclaim pages and manage memory.
    VirtualizationManager.Instance.UIThreadExcecuteAction = a => Dispatcher.Invoke( a );
    new DispatcherTimer( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 1 ),
                         DispatcherPriority.Background,
                         delegate
                         {
                           VirtualizationManager.Instance.ProcessActions();
                         },
                         Dispatcher ).Start();
}
```

My first question is what the heck is it doing?

I know we are using lambda expressions, and that (a) "goes to" the Dispatcher.Invoke(a), but is (a) the DispatchTimer? Does the UIThreadExectuteAction become the Dispatch.Invoke call? Does it pass to Dispatch.Invoke whatever we set to it?

My second question is that in UWP, Dispatcher.Invoke doesn't exist and from what I can tell is replaced with await dispatcher.RunAsync(...). I think I can wrap the Dispatcher.RunAsyc in a Task somehow, but the UIThreadExcecuteAction is an Action.

Is it possible to translate this to work in a Windows Universal App?

Comment: Why do you need "VirtualizingObservableCollection"? Standart UWP list controls like ListView and GridView are having great virtualization out of a box.

Comment: Probably because OP has very large datasets. I am using a dynamic dataset that can have millions of records in my application. At around 350,000 in memory, my app dies from lack of memory because I am keeping the ObservableCollection objects full of records around. Thus, I need to virtualize my data store as well. I am trying to use VirtualizingObservableCollection, but not having much luck so far....

Comment: It was indeed the size, or potential size of my dataset, in my case images (pictures). We ended up implementing a backing database store for our ObservableCollection using Volante  [link](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/volante/database.html) to flush to a temp file on disk. It handled the "virtualization" as I incrementally loaded  my images.